# Android - getFilesDir() not working (red in Android Studio)

Tags: android

Im trying to write a class that saves images on disk.

Inside class I have method `public static String saveToSdCard(Bitmap bitmap, String filename)` and inside it I try to get a reference to files folder by using `File path = new File(getFilesDir(), "myfolder");`but I cant because IDE marks it red.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/files.html before ask!

Answer (score 5):

You have to call it on the context.
Make sure you are in an Activity, or otherwise call it on a context instance, like `getActivity().getFilesDir()` or `context.getFilesDir()`, or even `view.getContext().getFilesDir()`.